# Custom ToC — Put vspace only below chapters that have sections in them

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, conditionals, titletoc

I’m using the [`titletoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) package in the `book` class. Currently, my chapter entries are configured like this (I left out the unimportant parameters for simplicity):

```
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pc]
{\addvspace{1pc}}
{}
{}
{}
[\addvspace{4pt}]
```

Look at that `4pt` space below the chapter entry. I want to change this such that this `4pt` space does *not* appear when there are no sections in the chapter. It should only appear for chapters with sections. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Could you please make your code minimal complete from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` so we do not need to rewrite it whole will all settings?

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way to do it:

- Define a boolean switch `\ifafterchapter`;
- Redefine (or simply use the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package and patch) the internal commands responsible for typesetting `\chapter` and lower-level sectioning headings so that a line in the `.toc` file is added setting the above boolean switch to `true` after `\chapter` and to `false` after `\section` and everything below;
- In the `titletoc` definition for section ToC entries (namely, in the "before" argument), add vertical space dependend on the state of `\ifafterchapter`.

---

```
\documentclass{book}

\newif\ifafterchapter

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\@makechapterhead}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterchaptertrue}%
}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@xsect}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterchapterfalse}%
}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{chapter}
    [1.5em]
    {\addvspace{1pc}\bfseries}
    {\contentslabel{1.5em}}
    {\hspace*{-1.5em}}
    {\hfill\contentspage}
\titlecontents{section}
    [3.8em] % ie, 1.5em (chapter) + 2.3em
    {\ifafterchapter\addvspace{4pt}\fi}
    {\contentslabel{2.3em}}
    {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
    {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}

\chapter{Second}

\section{Second-First}

\section{Second-Second}

\chapter{Third}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's different approach, not requiring additional packages; the idea is to redefine `\section` as implemented in `book.cls`. In the redefinition you test for the value of the `section` counter; if the value is greater than one, do nothing; if it's equal to one, add the space to the ToC::

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{chapter}
    [1.5em]
    {\addvspace{1pc}\bfseries}
    {\contentslabel{1.5em}}
    {\hspace*{-1.5em}}
    {\hfill\contentspage}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
  {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries%
      \ifnum\value{section}>1 \else \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{4pt}}\fi}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\chapter{Second}
\section{Second-First}
\section{Second-Second}
\chapter{Third}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the help of the `etoolbox` package, the code simplifies a little:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\titlecontents{chapter}
    [1.5em]
    {\addvspace{1pc}\bfseries}
    {\contentslabel{1.5em}}
    {\hspace*{-1.5em}}
    {\hfill\contentspage}

\patchcmd{\section}{\bfseries}%
 {\bfseries\ifnum\value{section}>1 \else \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{4pt}}\fi}{}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\chapter{Second}
\section{Second-First}
\section{Second-Second}
\chapter{Third}

\end{document}
```