# How to create additional space below Section headings followed by Subsections in the Table of Contents

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, tocloft, apa6, setspace

I am preparing my thesis using the apa6 document class. I'm using the tocloft package to format my Table of Contents and List of Figures. In the TOC, I can't figure out how to add space BELOW section headers that are followed by a subsection (required formatting of my University). I'm trying to make the space the same as observed for sections w/out any subsections.

```
\documentclass[man,12pt,natbib]{apa6}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}  
\usepackage{tocloft}


% Preamble w/ Table of Contents formatting.
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont}  % Make Section Headers Not bold in TOC
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\normalfont} % Make Section Numbers Not bold in TOC
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}   % W/out this command, it is not all capital letters.
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\normalfont} % Line 1/2 to center Heading
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}                       % Line 2/2 to center Heading
\renewcommand{\cftsecdotsep}{1}   % Line of Dots next to Section  {4.5 default}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecdotsep}{1}  % Line of Dots next to Subsection
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\normalfont\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}} % Makes Dots for Sections not Bold in TOC

\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{36pt}  % Space after TOC Header
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{10pt} % Space Between Sections
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{-8pt} % Gets subsections close together


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection {section}{1}
{\z@}
{\b@level@one@skip}
{\e@level@one@skip}
{\centering\normalfont\normalsize}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{2}
{\z@}
{\b@level@two@skip}
{\e@level@two@skip}
{\centering\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tocloftpagestyle{empty}  % No page numbers
\tableofcontents

\section{Section need added space below}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Another Subsection}
\section{In TOC, this Section has correct spacing above \& below for required thesis format}
\section{Section need added space below}
\subsection{Another Subsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I can't compile this example

Comment: Hmm...It compiles on TexShop Version 3.48.1 (3.48.1).   Thoughts?

Comment: Found a mistake and I've inserted  \makeatother into the MWE.

Comment: Your example does not compile. Note that 'It compiles...' means 'I tried ***exactly this code*** and it compiled without error'.  You should check this ***before*** posting your code. Also, remove unnecessary packages - if they aren't required to show the issue, you don't need them.

Comment: So I've simplified things by removing packages and options. In the preamble that remains, all text relates to the TOCs. The code does compile  exactly as shown using TexShop Version 3.48.1. There are a couple "Undefined control sequence errors" that pop-up, but it's easy to just press enter to get the document to compile.  My thoughts are that what I am hoping to achieve is tricky using "apa6" document class.

Comment: I found the solution on StackExchange, but it has to do with article document class. Not sure how to get this work with apa6 document class...http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53126/how-to-change-vertical-spacing-in-toc-between-section-entry-and-only-the-first-s

Answer (score 2):

You probably want what is described here: http://texblog.org/2013/07/16/how-to-add-extra-space-to-the-table-of-contents-list-of-figures-and-tables/